# Timeout interval in synchronous download procedure iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I have created request as below,

```
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:JsonURL];
[request setTimeoutInterval:10];

[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

But here time out interval is not working,I checked some questions on stack some said default time out is 75 seconds and some said it's 240 seconds,I am confused here ..

please help me with this.

Comment: The documentation clearly states: The default timeout interval is 60 seconds.

Comment: @Pfitz can you give me document link?

Comment: Sure. Here you go [NSMutableURLRequest Class Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableURLRequest/setTimeoutInterval:)

Comment: @Pfitz thanks for this it's clearly mentioned there about 60 seconds,so after 60 second Connection - didFailWithError:(NSError *)error will be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a synchronous connection. So there will be **no** calls to a delegate. If you still want to use a synchrous URL request I would recommend the following:

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if (nil == response) {
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
        [error localizedDescription],
        [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
    }
}
```

If you are want to use the delegate method you have to use an asynchronous request.

Please check the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE) too.